# NPM permissions error after package install

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I'm a new user to Node and npm, working on Mac OSX 10.7.5. Here's what I did:

1. Installed the node-v0.10.31.pkg from the Node website.
2. Everything worked. The Node REPL works fine.
3. npm does not work. If I type `$ npm install learnyounode -g`, I get this error: `-bash: npm: command not found`

I understand npm is supposed to ship with node, so I don't understand why this is an issue. Browsing through some other responses to diagnose the problem...

`$ /usr/local/bin/npm` results in this message:
`-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: Permission denied`

`$ which npm` does not produce any result.

I've seen some say to use this command: `curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`. But, I'm worried about installing over an existing install, and making things way way worse.

Can someone walk me through what my next step should be? Note that I'm not familiar with things like Homebrew, which I've also seen as a potential solution...

Thanks in advance. I just don't want to screw up my computer.

Comment: rather than using the pkg installer, using the [brew](http://brew.sh) package manager is going to give better results.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will running the brew package installer cause issues because there's already an installed package? Should I do a clean sweep of Node/npm? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have access to my /usr/local/lib. I fixed this by typing this into the Terminal:

`$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local`

From a lot of reading, this kind of action is pretty standard and safe. Once I did that, npm could be accessed, and no reinstall was needed! Phew!!